# How to plot subgraph of a networkx multipartite graph as a new graph with refreshed positions

Tags: python, networkx, hvplot

NetworkX offers `G.subgraph(node_list)` but when I plot it, it retains the node positions in the original full multipartite graph which is messy. I want the subgraph to be recalculated as a new plot (relatively centered) still retaining its multipartite layers but cleaner in terms of nodes vertical position. I'm using hvplot for displaying the graph using `hvplot.networkx as hvnx`. Additionally with this subplot from hvplot, there are some strange lines coming from the graph [image]which don't show when i just use nx.draw(G.subgraph(node_list), pos)[image].

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved both the problems.

1. by creating new position layout by passing in the subgraph instead of main graph.
2. corrected `hvnx` output by converting the graph to undirected.

```
GU = G.subgraph(node_list).to_undirected()
pos = nx.multipartite_layout(GU, subset_key="layer")
hvnx.draw(GU, pos)
```